# JSON schema (2020-12) to scala case classes

Tags: scala, akka, jsonschema

I am unable to find any library to convert nested JSON schema(2020-12)  to scala case classes for scala project.
I am using api first approach, so its necessary.
Found few projects supporting scala case class to JSON Schema but none for JSON schema to scala case class.

Looking for something like this

Example JSON:

```
  {
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$id": "http://example.com/product.schema.json",
  "title": "Product",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "productId": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "tags": {
      "description": "Tags for the product",
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "minItems": 1,
      "uniqueItems": true
    },
    "dimensions": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "length": {
          "type": "number"
        },
        "width": {
          "type": "number"
        },
        "height": {
          "type": "number"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "length"
      ]
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "productId",
    "price"
  ]
}
```

Converted to:

```
    case class Product (
     productId: Int,
     tags: Option[List[String]],
     dimensions: Option[Dimensions]
){
    assert( tags.get.length >= 1,  "`tags.get` violates 'minItems' constraint" )
    assert( tags.get.length == tags.get.distinct.length,  "`tags.get` violates 'uniqueItems' constraint" )
}


/**
 * @param length
 * @param width
 * @param height
 */
case class Dimensions (
     length: Double,
     width: Option[Double],
     height: Option[Double]
)
```

Comment: Well, it can't be a library since you don't want to generate new case classes definitions dynamically in runtime, do you? - Thus, you actually only need a tool that can do that and a quick google search pointed to a few, including one that uses exactly your own example: https://cchandurkar.github.io/json-schema-to-case-class/ I also found this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-schema-to-case-class

Comment: One could conceivably write a build plugin (e.g. an sbt plugin) along the lines of https://github.com/sbt/sbt-protobuf which consumes JSON Schema and emits `case class`es in, e.g. `target/<scala-version>/src_managed/main/from_json-schema`.

Comment: yes i don't want it to create at runtime  but on compile time.
I have already looked at this tool (both are same), i can give it a json schema and case classes gets generated manually and its awesome.
I actually want similar thing like guardrail (https://guardrail.dev/scala/akka-http/) that creates  scala case classes on compile time based on api doc with OpenAPI specs 3.0 (API First approach)
I need it for JSON schema